# Число (мн. или ед.) глагола при числительном

Tags: согласование, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число

Подскажите, в каком числе правильно поставить глагол?
*С 1 января вступают /вступает в действие пять новых федеральных стандартов...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это статистическое сообщение, которое на этом заканчивается, то акцент на *количестве* (труда разработчиков стандартов) - вступа**ет** *столько-то*. Если же далее через двоеточие перечислены *названия* стандартов, то это равносильно сообщению: *вот как**ие*** пять вступа**ют**.

Comment: "Через двоеточие." А если нет двоеточия (как и в вопросе, кстати), то..?

Answer (score 1):

*Пять стандартов* — это подлежащее, выраженное счетным оборотом.

О сказуемом: форма единственного числа указывает на общую совокупность предметов, форма множественного числа — на отдельные предметы.
*В стране строится пять стадионов* (единое нерасчленимое представление о действии).
*В крупнейших городах строятся ещё пять стадионов* (расчленённое представление о действии).

[Согласование сказуемого и подлежащего](http://www.mylanguage.ru/materials/127/3139)

Таким образом, выбор числа сказуемого зависит от контекста и смысла.
В нашем случае я бы предпочла все-таки множественное число глагола, потому что каждый из стандартов обычно вступает в силу на основании собственного закона или постановления.

*С первого января **вступают** в действие пять новых федеральных стандартов...*
 *Пять технических регламентов Таможенного союза **вступают** в действие с 1 июля 2012 года.*